# Java How do I figure out who has highest votes, and the remaining 4 winners?

Tags: java

So this is problem
In a city council election, 24 candidates are running for 5 seats. The candidate with the most votes becomes the city supervisor; the next 4 candidates become ordinary city council representatives. The remaining 19 candidates go back to their lives of quiet despair.

Attached to this dropbox, you will find a plaintext votes file containing approximately 19,000 votes cast for the 24 candidates. The candidates are numbered from 1 to 24, and each ballot is represented by a single line with the number of the selected candidate.

Here are the candidates. (Note that the names are unique for the sake of this example; don’t worry about the two Harrisons or Cleveland’s nonconsecutive terms.)
1.  Washington
2.  Adams
3.  Jefferson
4.  Madison
5.  Monroe
6.  Quincy Adams
7.  Jackson
8.  Van Buren
9.  Harrison
10. Tyler
11. Polk
12. Taylor
13. Fillmore
14. Pierce
15. Buchanan
16. Lincoln
17. Johnson
18. Grant
19. Hayes
20. Garfield
21. Arthur
22. Cleveland
23. McKinley
24. Roosevelt

For this problem, write an

- Election class with an appropriate main() method that reads in the
  votes file and prints out the names of the 5 council-seat winners, in
  order. It should print the city supervis

or first, and the remaining 4 winners, in descending order of number of votes.

Use a priority queue to implement this program.

Make sure your program can appropriately handle any number of council-seat winners, any number of candidates, and any input file. I.e., have all that information in variables, not hard-coded.

Although the supplied votes file has “good” data, your code should be prepared for bad data too. Consider edge cases such as a vote for a candidate that does not exist, a hanging chad, that kind of thing.

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class Election {
    static int count1=0, count2=0, count3=0, count4=0, count5=0,count6=0,count7=0,count8=0,count9=0,count10=0,count11=0,count12=0,count13=0,count14=0,count15=0,count16=0,count17=0,count18=0,count19=0,count20=0,count21=0,count22=0,count23=0,count24=0;
    static String line;
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException 
      {

        PriorityQueue<Integer> listpeople = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\votes.txt");    

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file);

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(line);
            listpeople.add(a);
            }
        in.close();
    for (int i = 0; i <= listpeople.size(); i++)
    {
    if (listpeople.poll() == 1)
    {
        count1++;
    }
    else if(listpeople.poll() == 2)
    {
        count2++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 3)
    {
        count3++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 4)
    {
        count4++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 5)
    {
        count5++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 6)
    {
        count6++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 7)
    {
        count7++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 8)
    {
        count8++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 9)
    {
        count9++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 10)
    {
        count10++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 11)
    {
        count11++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 12)
    {
        count12++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 13)
    {
        count13++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 14)
    {
        count14++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 15)
    {
        count15++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 16)
    {
        count16++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 17)
    {
        count17++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 18)
    {
        count18++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 19)
    {
        count19++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 20)
    {
        count20++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 21)
    {
        count21++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 22)
    {
        count22++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 23)
    {
        count23++;
    }
    else if (listpeople.poll() == 24)
    {
        count24++;
    }   
    }
    int [] anArray = new int [24];
    anArray[0] = count1;
    anArray[1] = count2;
    anArray[2] = count3;
    anArray[3] = count4;
    anArray[4] = count5;
    anArray[5] = count6;
    anArray[6] = count7;
    anArray[7] = count8;
    anArray[8] = count9;
    for(int i =0; i<9; i++)
    {
    System.out.println(anArray[i]);
    }

      }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? what is going wrong?

Comment: @Martin Serrano, so I determine how many votes for each candidates, but how do I determine which number of votes correspond to who

Comment: I would assume that to handle any number of council members/file location you would need to get that from the user. Having them stored as variables is hardcoded.

Comment: Ugly code.  Why do you need that bunch of if/else if constructs?  Java's an object-oriented language.  I'd have a Candidate class with name + vote data members.  I'd make it Comparable so I could sort Candidates by votes received.

Comment: @Mathemats, you're right, I read a file which contains 19,000 votes ( 1 for Washington, 2 for Adams .... ) then I count them all, how many votes for Washington, how many votes for Adams .... but I'm stuck at this point, I dont know how to determine which number of votes corresponds to who. (sorry bad English)

Comment: @HienVo We are on different paths. I am talking about prompting the user to enter the location of the input file and prompting for the number of candidates.

Comment: Isn't count1 the number votes for Washington, count2 the number of votes for Adams, etc.?

Comment: @jas, yes it is.
Sorry, I'm super new in Computer Science field, just trying to study.

Comment: there is the file which contains votes http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/226/hw6/data/ballots , so I copy all of them then change it to a text file, then read it.

Comment: @gaconus could you take a look at my answer and see if its on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Election {
    static String line;
    public static int highestLocation(int[] x){
        int max = 0, value = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            if (x[i] > max){
                max = x[i];
                value = i;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PriorityQueue<Integer> listpeople = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\votes.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file);

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(line);
            listpeople.add(a);
        }
        in.close();
        int[] candidates = new int[24];
        for (int i = 0; i <= listpeople.size(); i++) {
            int x = listpeople.poll();
            candidates[x-1]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int next = highestLocation(candidates);
            System.out.println((next+1) + " " + candidates[next]);
            candidates[next] = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Output for your data set:

```
8 2730
1 1669
6 1653
2 1495
5 1474
9 112
3 103
10 77
7 44
```

Comment: @lacgrai2, I appreciate it, I think I got this part, but I deleted it. The reason is I dont know the number 2730 is belong to who, and 1669, and 1653 ...

Comment: The candidate number in each case is (next + 1), so you just need to print that along with the vote count.

Comment: @gaconus I made the necessary changes. This should print correctly.

Comment: @jas I saw that on my own after his question, but good catch. Thanks.

Comment: @lacraig, please forgive me, I just didn't look carefully. Thank you very much, I think that your solution is what I'm looking for. Thank you everyone else :)

Comment: @gaconus you seem to be quite new here so I should tell you that once you find a solution click the check mark by the correct solution. Under the arrows. Thanks. Hope this helps.

Comment: oh, I clicked it, thank you again and have a great day @lacraig2, and also, is there anyway I can contact with you? There is no one I can ask directly when I'm stuck.

Comment: @gaconus as of the moment StackOverflow does not employ a personal messaging system, but even if they did there is no way that I could supply the personal attention and knowledge of thousands of programmers taking time out of their day to answer questions. The best way to get an answer when you're stuck is to go here and ask. When you get good enough go back and start answering questions. Hope that helps.

Comment: @lacraig2, I see, thank you again and have a great day, your code is very simple and easy to understand for me !